# Pass data from recyclerview to firebase

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, mobile, android-recyclerview

I try to save data from recyclerview to firebase, but there are an error, because the data are null, and i don't know why

**Recyclerview code**
[image]

[image]

**Class**

[image]

**Pass data**

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).  Please respond using @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Here you are actually saving it firebase and then assigning the value.When you create object value for student there will not value.
Also additional note, as per your code when give `adapter.names.String()` will save all the names in a single field in firebase database.

```
private fun SaveStudents (student: Students) {
     var database = Firebase.database.reference 
     student.idStudent = UUID.randomUUID().tostring
     student.name = adapter.names.toString()
     student.noControl = adapter.details.toString()
     //Student data populated
     //Then save it to firebase.
     database.child("students").child(student.idStudent).setValue(student)
}
```